# Force copy assignment over move assignment operator

Tags: c++, move, copy-constructor, move-constructor

Assume I have an object with both copy and move assignment operators defined. When I write this:

```
Object a(/*parameters 1*/);
/* some code */
a = Object(/*parameters 2*/);
```

the third line will most likely invoke the move assignment operator. How can I force the compiler to use copy assignment instead? Relatedly, how do I force copy over move constructors? Basically I am asking for a reverse std::move()

Why would I want this?

The code in between lines 1 and 3 (which I cannot change) acquires some pointers to the fields of `a`, i.e. it is important the memory layout of `a` is not altered (what move most likely does), but rather overwritten with new values.

Furthermore, my object is just the `std::vector`. When I move assign it, the compiler will just redirect the pointer of its underlying array to the array of the rvalue vector. When I copy assign it (and the previous vector `a` was longer) then its underlying array will be overwritten but their addresses will stay the same. The "some code" unfortunately stores pointers like `&a[2]`, and they may not change.

Comment: The layout or location of `a` can't be altered, only its members' values. ("Moving" doesn't actually move anything, and `std::move` is just a cast.)

Comment: Move won't change the layout of `a` at all, it will just move new values into place, exactly what you want I think?  The difference between move and copy is whether the _source_ of the data is changed.

Comment: And with that, a real example of what "acquires some pointers to the fields of `a` " actually *means* ?. If it's `int *p = &a.member;`, where `a.member` is some type that doesn't overload `operator &`, you have no worries. If it's `int *p = a.myvec.data();`, your concerns are founded.

Comment: You should clarify more what the intent is here. The type of respective fields that you have pointers to is relevant and how the move/copy is implemented can also be relevant. Do you have any influence over `/* some code */`? The design smells a bit bad.

Comment: Given `auto a = std::vector{1, 2, 3}; auto b = &a[0]; a = std::vector{1, 2};`, `b` will no longer point to `a[0]` after `a` is moved-into.  But if `a`'s storage is kept (a la `std::vector`'s copy constructor but *only* if the storage doesn't have to increase), then `b` stays valid.  I think that's what this question is after?

Comment: can you please show a concrete example of code in place of `/* some code */` that you think would cause problems when moving?

Comment: This could be a use-case for `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`. That way you can guarantee that the pointer will not change.

Answer (score 2):

#### Passing *lvalues* to the assignment operator

One way would be to pass an *lvalue* instead of an *rvalue* to the assignment operator of the object you are assigning to:

```
Object a(/*parameters 1*/);
Object b(/*parameters 2*/);
// ...
a = b; // <-- b is an lvalue, copy not move
```

This way, `a`'s *copy assignment operator* will be selected.

---

#### Qualifying the not-to-be-moved object as `const`

Another approach would be to `const`-qualify the object you don't want to be moved. This works even if you have an assignment where `std::move()` is already being used because `const`-qualified objects don't bind to *rvalue references*. Therefore, the move assignment operator won't be selected. That is:

```
const Object b(/*parameters 2*/);
// ...
a = std::move(b); // <-- still copies, b is const
```

Even if `b` above is explicitly marked for moving with `std::move(b)`, `a`'s copy assignment operator is selected.

Answer (score 2):

> My object is just the `std::vector`. When I move assign it, the compiler will just redirect the pointer of its underlying array to the array of the rvalue vector. When I copy assign it (and the previous vector a was longer) then its underlying array will be overwritten but their addresses will stay the same. The "some code" unfortunately stores pointers like `&a[2]`, and they may not change.

You'll need something else than copy assignment then, because copy assignment is not safe either.

Sure, this example works:

```
auto a = std::vector{1, 2};
auto const b = std::vector{3, 4};

auto pointer = a.data() + 1; // points to second element

a = b; // copy

std::cout << *pointer; // prints 4?
```

**This may work, but not always!**

Consider this:

```
auto a = std::vector{1, 2};
auto const b = std::vector{3, 4, 5}; // three elements!

auto pointer = a.data() + 1; // points to second element

a = b; // copy. a's buffer is too small, must reallocate

std::cout << *pointer; // points in the old buffer, invalid.
```

Pointer to elements of a vector that is then assigned is **not safe**!

---

What can you do then?

Define your own operation:

```
struct Object {
    // ... stuff

    auto safe_assign(Object const& other) & -> void {
        mem1 = other.mem1;
        mem2 = other.mem2;

        // let 'mem_vec' be your memeber vector
        assert(mem_vec.size() == other.mem_vec.size());

        // safe copy, will never reallocate.
        std::copy(other.mem_vec.begin(), other.mem_vec.end(), mem_vec.begin());
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Just like `std::move` takes a object and returns a rvalue reference to it, you can make a `copy` that takes a object and returns a lvalue reference to it.  That would look like

```
template< class T >
constexpr std::remove_reference_t<T>& copy( T&& t ) noexcept
{
    return t;
}
```

and you would use it like

```
a = copy(Object(/*parameters 2*/));
```

Comment: As `std::move` doesn't *move*, your `copy` doesn't *copy*. Fine :-)

Comment: Uniform initialization that isn't uniform, move that doesn't move anything, why not a copy that doesn't copy anything ;)